# Can't make php-CURL run on Centos server using php 7.2.5

Tags: php, curl, centos7, php-curl

I have CentOS server version 7.7 with nginx and PHP 7.2.5 installed
I have installed curl with

```
sudo yum install curl
```

and I got this

Package curl-7.29.0-54.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version

I have installed php curl using

```
sudo yum install php-curl
```

> Package php-common-7.2.24-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed

I restart nginx server using

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
```

but still I can't see curl running on server, any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by: "but still I can't see curl running on server, any ideas?" do you mean you have called php info and can't see it listed, or you cant actually use the curl command within a php file? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
sudo yum install php7.2-curl
```

It is possible, you have few php version installed on your server, and you try to install php-curl (for example to php5.6). It this case you don't use this version.
Also you need restart php-fpm, because nginx restarting doesn't restart php-fpm

```
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```

Comment: I got No package php7.2-curl available. and after restarting php-fpm nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I have 2 versions one compiled and another one installed on the system

I have downloaded an updated version of PHP and compile it with curl support to replace the current one.